# Issue with getting the key using Spring Boot with Redis Data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, redisson

I am trying to save an access token within Redis. I have created the RedisConfig, RedisRepository which extends CrudRepository.

In the call where i get the access token i am using the repository to save it in Redis which is working fine.

tokenRepository.save(tokenResponse);

However when i try to read the saved values i am getting a null value. I have tried with both findById(id) and findByAll().

```
    Iterable<Token> token1 = tokenRepository.findAll();
    LOG.info("Token ="+token1.toString());
```

The Model class has the @Indexed and @Id property on the "access_token".

```
@Id
@Indexed
private String access_token;
```

Any help is appreciated.